# Redirect is not working after checking Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

From my below script i request the status from index2.html.

My `http://test1.info/portal/#portal` cannot be reached (Chrome) or displayed (IE). Since the URL is "404" or not reached it is not redirecting it to `index3.html`

```js
function website() {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open('GET', 'http://mytest.info/index2.html', true);
  alert(req.status);
  req.send();

  if (req.status != "200"
    || "404") {
    window.location.href = "http://test1.info/portal/#portal";
  } else {
    alert("123");
    alert(req.status);
    window.location.href = "http://test.example.info/index3.html";
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="website()" >
```

Where am I doing it wrong?

Comment: `or`? What language is this?

Comment: Always check the error console...

Comment: @CristianTraìna that was an example

Answer (score 0):

There are some typos in your code:

1. there is a `)` in your `body` tag
2. you haven't closed your `body` tag
3. in the `if` condition you used `or`, which doesn't exist in JS (it's `||`), but in your case your logic should be the following: `req.status != "200" && req.status != "404"`

Once you fix these issues, your code should work:

```js
function website() {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open('GET', 'http://mytest.info/index2.html', true);
  alert(req.status);
  req.send();

  if (req.status != "200" && req.status != "404") {
    window.location.href = "http://test1.info/portal/#portal";
  } else {
    alert("123");
    alert(req.status);
    window.location.href = "http://test.example.info/index3.html";
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="website()"></body>
```

Comment: sorry for typo in the code, i have corrected and tried but i still go to the test1.info. Although url is not accessible i am landing on this url. And receiving req.status 0

Comment: if `req.status` is 0 then you have to check console :)

Comment: i see undefined  when i check on console